# How do I insert null into an integer field with VBA?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, insert

I have an MS Access ADP with a SQL server backend. I want to take a bunch of values from a form and insert them into a table. Some of the values can be null. How do I use vba to insert null into an integer field in the SQL Server table?

I tried

```
"insert...values(" & nz(me.myInt, null) & ",..."
```

and

```
"insert...values(" & nz(me.myInt, "null") & ",..."
```

Neither worked.

Comment: the thing that i'm running into is your nz... if me.myint IS null... isnt it enough just to put THAT value in w/o the nz around it?.. unless me is inside its own class module... then any property of me cannot be null..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF the field will accept nulls then simply leave it out of the list of fields and it will get a null value. So given a table with Name, Address, phone, doing the equivalent of

```
INSERT table(Name, Address) VALUES('fred','Toytown')
```

will leave the phone number with a null value

Answer (score 3):

your second example looks good

("insert...values(" & nz(me.myInt, "null") & ",...")

but only if me.myInt is a variant, a control, or a field.  If myInt is an integer or a long, then it cannot be null.

Answer (score 1):

what error are you getting when you run your code?

say we have  table... [test] with columns [id], [test] and [test 2].

you could write;

```
insert into [test] ([test], [test 2]) values ( null, null)
```

make sure that your string that you are passing the command in on shows the null w/o any kind of decoration... no single or double quotes.

Comment: I found a solution: 
1) Add a numeric field to the table with null default value (called NullValue) 
2) if you want to assign null to another field: rst!Field = rst!NullValue